# how to select two column from two different tables using join

Tags: mysql, join

problem statement:- take records from two table one is attendence and second is visits about particular user and between particular dates

i have two tables one is attendence and second is visits

1) attendence

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| user        | date_today | in_time             |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| MCCuser0036 | 25-02-2019 | 25-02-2019 10:59:08 |
| MCCuser0036 | 12-03-2019 | 12-03-2019 10:59:54 |
| MCCuser0036 | 14-03-2019 | 14-03-2019 11:01:11 |
| MCCuser0036 | 25-01-2019 | 25-01-2019 11:02:09 |
| MCCuser0036 | 25-03-2019 | 25-03-2019 11:03:10 |
| MCCuser0035 | 25-03-2019 | 25-03-2019 11:39:38 |
| MCCuser0036 | 26-03-2019 | 26-03-2019 11:30:47 |
| MCCuser0036 | 27-03-2019 | 27-03-2019 10:36:30 |
| MCCuser0036 | 28-03-2019 | 28-03-2019 17:18:01 |
| MCCuser0036 | 01-04-2019 | 01-04-2019 15:29:08 |
| MCCuser0036 | 08-04-2019 | 08-04-2019 23:01:57 |
| MCCuser007  | 26-04-2019 | 26-04-2019 20:04:36 |
| MCCuser0036 | 27-04-2019 | 27-04-2019 21:06:17 |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
```

2) visits

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| username    | add_time   | visit_time_in       |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| MCCuser0036 | 13-02-2019 | 13-02-2019 11:46:55 |
| MCCuser0036 | 14-02-2019 | 14-02-2019 11:47:04 |
| MCCuser0036 | 14-02-2019 | 14-02-2019 11:51:07 |
| MCCuser0036 | 14-02-2019 | 14-02-2019 11:51:30 |
| MCCuser0036 | 14-02-2019 | 14-02-2019 11:51:36 |
| MCCuser0036 | 18-02-2019 | 18-02-2019 15:09:42 |
| MCCuser0036 | 20-02-2019 | 20-02-2019 12:11:30 |
| MCCuser0036 | 25-02-2019 | 25-02-2019 13:05:42 |
| MCCuser0036 | 11-03-2019 | 11-03-2019 12:48:28 |
| MCCuser0036 | 01-04-2019 | 01-04-2019 15:55:45 |
| MCCuser007  | 26-04-2019 | 26-04-2019 20:04:55 |
| MCCuser007  | 26-04-2019 | 26-04-2019 20:05:10 |
| MCCuser0036 | 27-04-2019 | 27-04-2019 21:06:55 |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
```

what i want is record of attendence and visits of particular user in a given date range in desc order.

my output should be like first attendence then all visits of that user of that day

```
+----------+------------------------+----------+---------------------+
|user      |in_time                 |username  |visit_time_in        |
+----------+------------------------+----------+---------------------+
|given user|attendence of given date|given user|visits of given user |
+----------+------------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

I'm using this query but it is giving me an empty set and warning and i dont have any deep knowledge of mysql and joins so i dont know im doing this by right way or not:

```
SELECT a.user,a.in_time,v.username,v.visit_time_in 
   FROM attendence AS a 
   INNER JOIN visits AS v ON a.user=v.username 
      WHERE a.user='MCCuser0036' 
      AND a.in_time BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-04-2019', '%d-%m-%Y') 
      AND STR_TO_DATE('27-04-2019', '%d-%m-%Y') 
   ORDER BY a.in_time,v.visit_time_in DESC; 

Empty SET, 22 WARNINGS (0.00 sec)
```

note: there is no primary and foreign key and date_today,in_time and add_time,visit_time_in and both user,username columns are varchar

**UPDATED EDIT** answer of @SebastianBrosch is what i wanted but i have more columns in my DB so after getting basic structure i added some columns to it and query for that is

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'attendence' AS 'type', user AS 'username', STR_TO_DATE(in_time, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS 'time_in', STR_TO_DATE(out_time, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS 'time_out', location_in as 'place_in' FROM attendence UNION ALL SELECT 'visit', username, STR_TO_DATE(visit_time_in, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'), STR_TO_DATE(visit_time_out, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'), in_address FROM visits) t WHERE t.username = 'MCCuser0036' AND time_in BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2019', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE('27-04-2019', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') ORDER BY time_in ASC;
```

but that is giving me an unexpected result

```
+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| type       | username    | time_in             | time_out            | address_in                                                                                                           | address_out                                                                                         |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| attendence | MCCuser0036 | 2019-01-25 11:02:09 | 2019-01-25 11:02:10 | in_address                                                                                                           | out_address                                                                                         |
| visit      | MCCuser0036 | 2019-02-13 11:46:55 | 2019-02-13 11:47:00 | Sewri - Chembur Rd, Trombay Indusrial Area, Antop Hill, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India                            | Sewri - Chembur Rd, Trombay Indusrial Area, Antop Hill, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India           |
| visit      | MCCuser0036 | 2019-02-14 11:47:04 | 2019-02-14 11:47:10 | Sewri - Chembur Rd, Trombay Indusrial Area, Antop Hill, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India                            | Sewri - Chembur Rd, Trombay Indusrial Area, Antop Hill, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India           |
| visit      | MCCuser0036 | 2019-02-14 11:51:07 | 2019-02-14 11:51:10 | Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India                                       | Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India                      |
| visit      | MCCuser0036 | 2019-02-14 11:51:30 | 2019-02-14 11:51:34 | Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India                                       | Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India                      |
| visit      | MCCuser0036 | 2019-02-14 11:51:36 | 2019-02-14 11:51:39 | Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India                                       | Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India                      |
| visit      | MCCuser0036 | 2019-02-18 15:09:42 | NULL                | Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India                                       |                                                                                                     |
| visit      | MCCuser0036 | 2019-02-20 12:11:30 | 2019-02-20 13:44:36 | Sewri - Chembur Rd, Trombay Indusrial Area, Antop Hill, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India                            | Building No 57, Gaurav Harmony, CGS Colony, Sector 7, Antop Hill, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India |
| attendence | MCCuser0036 | 2019-02-25 10:59:08 | 2019-02-25 10:59:16 | in_address                                                                                                           | out_address                                                                                         |
| visit      | MCCuser0036 | 2019-02-25 13:05:42 | NULL                | Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India                                       |                                                                                                     |
| visit      | MCCuser0036 | 2019-03-11 12:48:28 | NULL                | jay maharashNagar kokri agar S.M road anophill church Near By sayyed alam, musjid, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India |                                                                                                     |
| attendence | MCCuser0036 | 2019-03-12 10:59:54 | 2019-03-12 11:00:24 | in_address                                                                                                           | out_address                                                                                         |
| attendence | MCCuser0036 | 2019-03-14 11:01:11 | 2019-03-14 11:01:28 | in_address                                                                                                           | out_address                                                                                         |
| attendence | MCCuser0036 | 2019-03-25 11:03:10 | 2019-03-25 11:16:12 | in_address                                                                                                           | out_address                                                                                         |
| attendence | MCCuser0036 | 2019-03-26 11:30:47 | NULL                | in_address                                                                                                           | out_address                                                                                         |
| attendence | MCCuser0036 | 2019-03-27 10:36:30 | 2019-03-27 10:49:05 | in_address                                                                                                           | out_address                                                                                         |
| attendence | MCCuser0036 | 2019-03-28 17:18:01 | NULL                | in_address                                                                                                           | out_address                                                                                         |
| attendence | MCCuser0036 | 2019-04-01 15:29:08 | NULL                | in_address                                                                                                           | out_address                                                                                         |
| visit      | MCCuser0036 | 2019-04-01 15:55:45 | NULL                | 736, Aala Hazrat Rd, Jagruti Nagar, Nehru Nagar, Kurla East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400071, India                       |                                                                                                     |
| attendence | MCCuser0036 | 2019-04-11 15:17:56 | NULL                | in_address                                                                                                           | out_address                                                                                         |
| attendence | MCCuser0036 | 2019-04-23 17:41:05 | 2019-04-23 17:42:54 | in_address                                                                                                           | out_address                                                                                         |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

can anyone point me out why?

Comment: This looks like a simple join so what have you so far and what problem are you having?

Comment: i'm using this query (select a.user,a.in_time,v.username,v.visit_time_in from attendence as a inner join visits as v on a.user=v.username where a.user='MCCuser0036' and a.in_time BETWEEN str_to_date('01-04-2019', '%d-%m-%Y') and str_to_date('27-04-2019', '%d-%m-%Y') order by a.in_time,v.visit_time_in desc;
Empty set, 22 warnings (0.00 sec)) but it is giving me an empty set and warning and i dont have any deep knowledge of mysql and joins so i dont know im doing this by right way or not

Comment: "note: there is primary and foreign key" - Where?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel im sorry for typo actuall there is no primary and foreign key i have edited in original post

Comment: I don't see a meaningful relation between this two tables.  A UNION query would make more sense. Please post the expected result.

Comment: You should add your table defintions and your expected output. As is I cannot work out what you want. A simple inner join such as you have will result in a cartesian product which I am pretty sure you don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `STR_TO_DATE` on the `a.in_time` column too, to get a result:

```
SELECT a.user, a.in_time, v.username, v.visit_time_in 
FROM attendence AS a INNER JOIN visits AS v ON a.user = v.username 
WHERE a.user = 'MCCuser0036' 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(a.in_time, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-04-2019', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('27-04-2019', '%d-%m-%Y')
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(a.in_time, '%d-%m-%Y'), STR_TO_DATE(v.visit_time_in, '%d-%m-%Y') DESC;
```

You doesn't get a result because the condition `a.in_time BETWEEN str_to_date('01-04-2019', '%d-%m-%Y') and str_to_date('27-04-2019', '%d-%m-%Y')` can't be true since `a.in_time` is not a valid date value. You also have to use the `STR_TO_DATE` on the `ORDER BY` to get the records sorted with date values.

**Note:** You should use the `DATETIME` data type on columns `in_time`, `visit_time_in` and the `DATE` data type on `add_time` and `date_today`. So you can filter and sort without using a convert function (like `STR_TO_DATE`) first.

---

To get only the rows of the two tables with one query you can use a `UNION ALL` like this:

```
SELECT type, username, DATE_FORMAT(time_value, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS 'time_value'
FROM (
    SELECT 'attendence' AS 'type', `user` AS 'username', STR_TO_DATE(in_time, , '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'time_value'
    FROM attendence 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'visit', username, STR_TO_DATE(visit_time_in, '%d-%m-%Y')
    FROM visits
) t 
WHERE t.username = 'MCCuser0036'
    AND time_value BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-04-2019', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('27-04-2019', '%d-%m-%Y')
ORDER BY type, time_value DESC
```

Comment: actually i tried your first query but that is giving me an duplicate values from both the tables and your second query is exactly what i want thank you but i want little changes like i want first attendence then visits in type collumn and in time_value column date should be in original format like (%d-%m-%Y 00:00:00)

Comment: @Divyangpatel - updated the answer. now the attendence is the first on result and time_value is formatted to the original value.

Comment: hello @SebastianBrosch im getting an  ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'user' in 'field list'

Comment: @Divyangpatel - fixed (username instead of user)

Comment: hello @SebastianBrosch current query is only giving me an all attendence first then all visits i dont want like that i want one attendence then visits of that date and another attendence your previous query giving me first visits then attendence of that date

Comment: @Divyangpatel - you tried `time_value DESC, type` instead of `type, time_value DESC`?

Comment: it was ORDER BY time_value DESC; only but i changed to type, time_value DESC then still it is giving all attendence first and then all visits

Comment: i am getting unexpected result [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219406/giving-unexpected-result-in-mysql-query] this is a link can u have look at this once

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*,v.* from attendence as a
inner join visits as v on a.user = v.username
```

Comment: i have done that but it is giving me an duplicate records from both the tables

Comment: @Divyangpatel Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to avoid duplicate values

Comment: @harry no, no, no, no, no. These duplicates are caused by a faulty join condition; fix the join. Please never advocate use of DISTINCT in this context

Comment: hello @harry i tried distinct on column a.user by did not affect any thing got same result

Comment: hello @Mohasinali i want record of particular user about their attendence and below that record of visits in descending order

Comment: hello @CaiusJard thank you for pointing my mistack as sebastian said in other answer two column(in_time,visit_time_in) should be in correct format(date) which is not and also i had not used that str_to_date()